# How to fix Error ExecuteReader

Tags: c#

Error An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. How to fix it?
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sibc.png

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=QEAG1YU4664IBKF\HUYNHBAO;Initial Catalog=TonghopDB;User ID=sa;Password=koolkool7");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select Title from TongHopDB", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        dt.Load(reader);

        cboxDB.ValueMember = "Title";
        cboxDB.DisplayMember = "Title";
        cboxDB.DataSource = dt;

        conn.Close();
    }

    private void cboxDB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "Select Title, Post from TongHopDB where Title = " + cboxDB.SelectedValue.ToString(); // câu query có thể khác với kiểu dữ liệu trong database của bạn
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=QEAG1YU4664IBKF\HUYNHBAO;Initial Catalog=TonghopDB;User ID=sa;Password=koolkool7");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        textBox1.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
        sdr.Close();
        sdr.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `Title` column?

Comment: @Bao Kool you should select an answer if one of them has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string sql = "Select Title, Post from TongHopDB where Title = '" + cboxDB.SelectedValue.ToString()+"'";
```

However I strongly suggest to use parameters:

```
 string sql = "Select Title, Post from TongHopDB where Title = @Title";
cmd.Paramaters.Add( "@Title",cboxDB.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I *strongly* suspect your `Title` is character typed, that's why it needs to used with single quotes as;

```
where Title = '" + cboxDB.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
```

#### But don't use this way.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` objects automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=QEAG1YU4664IBKF\HUYNHBAO;Initial Catalog=TonghopDB;User ID=sa;Password=koolkool7"))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "Select Title, Post from TongHopDB where Title = @title";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboxDB.SelectedValue.ToString();
   // I assumed your column type is nvarchar.
   conn.Open();
   using(SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      if(dr.Read())
      {
         textBox1.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
         textBox2.Text = sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cboxDB.SelectedValue is Apple according to the error shown in your screen shot. Your SQL statement is saying in plain English:

Select Title(column) and Post(column) from TongHopDB(table) where Title(column) equals Apple(column)

`Apple` is not a valid column!

While it would work to simply add single quotes around the value of cboxDB, you should use parameters instead of concatenating a string. http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/